# How to Publish Website on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7

I am able to publish website by creating virtual directory under `Default Web Site` in IIS 7. In this case url becomes `http://localhost/ABC` where `ABC` is my website and it is working fine. But I have to publish website at same level to `Default Web Site`, not under it. In this case url becomes `http://ABC:81` where 81 is port number, but website is not working.
Can any body solve it?

Comment: You need to provide details.  Specifically, what is not working, how is it not working, are you getting any error messages, what have you tried...

Comment: then how can u use as hostname. you can use only localhost as hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for local PC we can use only

IP : 127.0.0.1 &
hostname : localhost

both redirect the to local PC
if you use http://ABC.com it will be check on DNS. so plz set hostname localhost and port 81.
so u can browse http://localhost:81. or u can set IP 127.0.0.1 and port 81 in binding so u can browse with http://127.0.0.1:81 also

Comment: +1 Thanks @Govind for your help now scenario is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the default web site and add yours to run on port 80.  You can only run one web site on one port on one hostname at a time.

EDIT:  After reading your post again, are you trying to access a different hostname for the second server?
`http://ABC:81` is not valid unless ABC is a valid hostname.  Change that to `http://localhost:81` to test your other site.

Comment: @Jams: yes, you can run multiple websites on different ports.

Comment: Yes you can, but you can only one run website on one port one one hostname at a time.   You are asking for port 80.  You can't have two websites running under the same hostname on the same port. Why the downvote?

Comment: `Default Web Site` is running on port 80 and mine on port 81

Comment: +1 Thanks @Max for your help now scenario is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for test purposes you can go to c:\windows\systen32\drivers\etc and edit host file and you can add:

> 127.0.0.1  abc

Then you can access your website through http://abc.
Or you may use `127.0.0.1 www.abc.com` in place